# Possible Scope problems in a JSF2 web application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, spring-3, mojarra

I´ve a JSF web application using SPRING3 + JSF2 (mojarra 2.1.12) and I´m having some problems that I think can be derived of a bad choose of the Scope of one controller in one combo of the JSF2+primefaces interface.

This combo functionality allows the user to choose one of the internal xhtml subpages and a button that automatically redirects you to that page.

The website uses a template technology: there is template (standard.xhtml) with the JSF2 code and using this template there are  several pages: a inicio.xhtml that is the home page and a contact page (contacto.xhtml). In both pages the combo is displayed properly.

The following code it is working properly only if you´re navigating at the home page (incio.xhtml) but when you´re in other part of the web (i.e. contacto.xhtml) it displays the combo with all the options, but the button doesn´t work at all.

Here it´s my code in standard.xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xml:lang="${userContext.locale}" lang="${userContext.locale}"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
       xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
       <h:head>
             //HEAD
       </h:head>
       <body>
             <div id="…">
                    <div id="…">

                           //CODE
                           //CODE to go from one page (inicio.xhtml) to other (contacto.xhtml)
                                  <li><h:commandLink value="${msg.app_menu_contacto}" action="mContacto" /></li>

                           //MORE CODE
                           <h:form>
                                  //MORE CODE
                                  <h:panelGrid id="buscar" columns="2" style="margin-top:20px;" cellpadding="5">
                                  <p:selectOneMenu id="selectBuscar" value="#{buscador.procedimiento}" panelStyle="width:150px;"  
                                         var="p" style="width:220px; margin-right: 10px; "  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">  
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="${msg.app_comun_seleccionar}" itemValue="" />  
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{buscador.procedimientos}" var="proc" itemLabel="#{proc.codigo}" itemValue="#{proc.valor}"/>
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                                              <p:commandButton id="btnIr" style="width:40px" value="#{msg.app_comun_btn_ir}" title="#{msg.app_comun_btn_ir_title}" 
                                                action="#{buscador.direccion}">
                                        </p:commandButton> 
                                  </h:panelGrid>
                                  </h:form>
                           </div>
                    </div>
       </body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

In the faces-navigation.xml we have these lines (faces-navigation is only used in several inherited parts of the code):

```
<navigation-case>
<from-outcome>mContacto</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/views/comun/contacto.xhtml</to-view-id>
<redirect />
</navigation-case>
```

Code of the xhtml home page where it is working:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
       xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
       xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
       template="/WEB-INF/layouts/standard.xhtml">

//Code independent of the combo or button failing
// it uses ui:define to show different components in the page.

    </ui:composition>
```

and this is the controller code:

```
@Controller("buscador")
//@Scope(“Session”)  Do not work with “request”, “view” or without scope
public class BuscadorController implements Serializable {

       public List<ValorCombo> getProcedimientos() {
             //Code that returns a list of pair String to show in the combo, name of the xhtml page should be redirected
}

public String direccion() {
//CODE
String salida = "proc/"+procedimiento+"?faces-redirect=true";
//more CODE
return salida;
}
```

}

I have tried this but it doesn´t work neither.

http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html

how can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `direccion()` method being hit?

Comment: Yes. the output is something like:

proc/functionName?var=0&amp;faces-redirect=true

Comment: That's the navigation outcome for the destination view. Using navigation cases (xml file) does not make sense at all when using JSF 2, unless you want to use conditional navigation. For your case, you can go to `contacto.xhtml` either returning `mContacto` or the view path `/views/comun/contacto` in the `direccion()` method.  However, in this case you are returning `proc/functionName`, does it match any of your paths?

Comment: Yes, using the combo the user select the functionName (which is the web page he wants to go) and when pressing the button it is expected to go there. This redirection is working in the inicio.xhtml but it is not working the same code (because it is in the template) when it is invoked from the contacto.xhtml page. For that I think it is a problem either of the scope of the bean or something related with how I go from incio.xhtml to contacto.xhtml but I cannot find the error

Comment: Could be just a path problem. You're specifying a relative path, and it works for `inicio` location but not for the other one. Switch to absolute one `/proc/functionName`.